# showing only first post when clicking read more of any post wordpress posts

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is showing only last created post when i am clicking on readmore button of post.

remember i have called all posts on another template(our_program.php inplace of index.php) all posts are showing well but on single.php here is only only one recent post showing when i am clicking on read more of any post. my single.php code is below

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post');
        query_posts($args);
     ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <section class="talent-development" id="telent-development">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="section-content-text clearfix">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <div class="ourProgramImg">
                                <?php if( has_post_thumbnail()){
                                    the_post_thumbnail(); 
                                }
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                            <div class="ourProgramContent">
                                <p>
                                    <?php the_content();?>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <!--<div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="section-content-img">
                        <img src="img/sec.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                    </div>
                </div>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?php endwhile;  else: ?>
    <p> Not post Found </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

and post page(permalink) code below

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post');
        query_posts($args);
     ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <section class="talent-development" id="telent-development">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="section-content-text clearfix">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <div class="ourProgramImg">
                                <?php if( has_post_thumbnail()){
                                    the_post_thumbnail(); 
                                }
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                            <div class="ourProgramContent">
                                <p>
                                    <?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0, 400); //the_content();?>
                                </p>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <!--<div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="section-content-img">
                        <img src="img/sec.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                    </div>
                </div>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p> Not post Found </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Why are you using `query_posts` in single.php? Wordpress already has the query set up correctly, and this is overriding it. Please review the [Wordpress's Theme Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/) to develop your themes correctly.

Comment: Got it, Thanks :)